# Why this different behaviour of clang and gcc

Tags: c++, g++, clang, language-lawyer

If you write the following program:

```
template <typename T>
struct A{
    A(T& xx):x{xx} {}

    template <int n>
    void f() {cout << n << '\n';}

    T& x;
};

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    A{x}.f<3>();
}
```

it compiles well in g++ 7.3 (-std = c++17), but gives the error "expected unqualified-id" with clang-6.0.

But if you instead of

```
A{x}.f<3>();
```

write

```
::A{x}.f<3>();
```

it compiles perfectly in both compilers. Why?

Comment: Works with [clang 7.0](https://godbolt.org/z/3YQBTM)

Comment: This is just a clang 6 bug in its experimental support for template argument deduction. Clang 7 and GCC 8 still have other various bug related to template argument deduction.